# Using SemaphoreSlim and Continuewith for downloading Urls

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to use `SemaphoreSlim` and `ContinueWith` to limit the number of concurrent tasks I'm running. But the run-time behavior differs my expectation a lot.

The value I've set for ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit equals to 288 and since I've initialized SemaphoreSlim(100), my expectation of the run-time behavior is that the code should spawn 100 threads first and then start a new task when the first task is completed.

```
var sr =
    new StreamReader(
        @"UrlList.tsv");

var urlList = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    string[] tokens = line.Split('\t');
    string url = tokens[4];
    urlList.Add(url);
}

ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12*Environment.ProcessorCount;
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "\t" + ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit);

var tasks = new Task[urlList.Count];
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(100);
var client = new HttpClient();
int cnt = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < urlList.Count; i++)
{
    int i1 = i;
    tasks[i] = semaphore.WaitAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "\t" + ++cnt);
        var t = client.GetStringAsync(urlList[i1]);
        Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
        semaphore.Release();
        return t.Result;
    });
}
Task.WhenAll(tasks).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

The output looks something like this:

```
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    288
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    1
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    7
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    10
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    11
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    12
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    3
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    4
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    2
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    5
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    8
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    6
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    9
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    21
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    17
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    14
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    15
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    13
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    22
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    16
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    23
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    20
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    19
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    24
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    25
4/6/2015 11:36:12 PM    18
4/6/2015 11:36:13 PM    26
4/6/2015 11:36:14 PM    27
4/6/2015 11:36:15 PM    28
```

So it seems the thread is not spawned in a way I would expect and no Url content is being shown as well. What exactly is the issue in my code?

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to do it manually? Both the TPL and PLINQ have mechanisms for parallel loops where you can just add the maximum degree of parallelism as parameters.

Comment: @nvoigt: Thanks for your comment but please correct me if I am wrong. I think basically I should only use Parallel.ForEach when my job is CPU bounded and async-await when my job is I/O bounded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try somethng like this:

```
async Task<IEnumerable<string>> DoItAsync(int threads, IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12*Environment.ProcessorCount;
    Console.WriteLine("{0:HH:mm:ss.ffffff}\t{1}", DateTime.Now, ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit);

    var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(threads);
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var cnt = 0;
    var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        tasks.Add(((Func<Task<string>>)(async () =>
            {
                await semaphore.WaitAsync();

                var c = ++cnt;
                Console.WriteLine("{0:HH:mm:ss.ffffff}\t{1}\t{2}", DateTime.Now, c, url);
                var s = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                Console.WriteLine("{0:HH:mm:ss.ffffff}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", DateTime.Now, c, url, s.Substring(0, 20));
                semaphore.Release();
                return s;
            }))());
    }

    return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: The use of `async/await` are improvements over the OP's code, but you do not want `Task.Run` (you're already getting a "hot" task from your async delegate), and I think you could simply `return await Task.WhenAll(...)` at the end.

Comment: Edited per my previous comments.

Comment: Actually Todd Menier, I'd prefer the former. See these two links: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/08/10265476.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

Comment: @ToddMenier, I was favoring readability. The async delegate is not a "hot" task but a delegate that returns a hot task when invoked. On your correction you were not invoking it and the code didn't even compile.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Right you are, my bad. (I should have tried to build it!) I do think what you've arrived at here (invoking the delegate) is preferable over forcing another thread into the mix with `Task.Run`. I'd probably extract the delegate to an async method for readability (avoid the awkward cast, etc), but correctness-wise this is an improvement. +1.

Comment: I also prefer not to force it into the thread pool. However, calling `Task.Run` will free the current thread to process the next item.